# Any python package to cluster edges of graph with node and link attributions?

Tags: python, graph-theory, node-cluster, complex-networks

I'm looking forward a link clustering method considering node and link attributions. Knowlegde fields: graph theory, complex network analysis, overlapping community detection, edge clustering.

#### Background

For complex network analysis, there are lots of tools/algorithms to implement node clustering for community detection. However, link clustering is not so attractive. So far, I found few python packages provide link clustering function like [CDlib](https://cdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/classes/edge_clustering.html), [SNAP](https://snap.stanford.edu/snap/description.html). They proposed the edge clustering algorithm based on the perspective that the overlapping community of one node can be simultaneously decided by the clusters of the edges linking to the node.

#### Expect

I tried to google keywords based on "python" like "link clustering", "edge clustering", "overlapping community dectection" and found nothing meeting my expection. So, do you guys know something about it? Or I just step into somewhere unexplored. I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is off topic and a reason to close questions.  Please review the rules and question guidelines *before* posting.